# Accents in php and mysql pdo

Tags: php, json, pdo

I need to read some values from DB in which I have accents in this way: "CafeterÃ­a" which real word is "Cafetería"

When I pass the json to the php script, it is like this:

```
{"attribution":"CafeterÃ­a"} 

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_post = json_decode($json, true);
$attribution = $json_post['attribution'];
```

But it is read wrong and doesn't give me any row from DB. I use PDO to read from DB.

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostDB;dbname=$nameDB;charset=UTF-8", $userDB, $passwordDB, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, title, lat, lon FROM POI_Table WHERE attribution=:attribution");
    $stmt->execute(array(':attribution'=>$attribution));
```

If I execute the same query in HEIDI but writing the value exactly as json file gives it, it work. How should I convert the value before using in query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are setting encoding for mysql wrong way.

It's `utf8` **without a dash**

the other answer is essentially wrong as it causes double extra recoding and works for lat1 characters only.

Comment: I will try, just a sec

Comment: I will try to see why it is failing. When I get something clear, I will post again.

Answer (score 0):

What about doing this in your code?

```
$json_post = json_decode(utf8_decode($json), true);
```

Comment: Perfect. I have a problem with accents. Every day I have to work with them is like a shoot to me.. Thank you man.

Comment: If this solve your problem don't forget to put your question as answered ;)

Comment: It said I have to wait a few minutes before I could. It is done ;)

Comment: Biribu I think @Your Common Sense is actually right you should try modifying the encoding of your mysql database ;)